# pycharm - how do i get rid of the "multiple rows of tabs" and just have one row, like, say, firefox or eclipse?

Tags: pycharm

As the title says, how do i just have one row in pycharm instead of that multiple rows thing. this is for the tabs of open files!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is an option to **Show tabs in single row**:

[image: single row]